# How to use AWS S3 REST API ListObjects(v2) with multiple parent/child bucket directories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, postman

What am I missing here?

I'm able to list objects no problem using the `aws cli` and this command:

`aws s3 ls s3://bucket.mycompany.com/parent-dir1/parent-dir2/`

But using the REST API via Postman, an equivalent request returns an empty response.

- **Tool:** Postman
- **Method:** GET
- **URl:**

  - `https://bucket.mycompany.com.s3.amazonaws.com/parent-dir1/parent-dir2/?list-type=2`
- **Auth:**
  [image]
- **Headers:**

  - I've tried with no headers and with `x-amz-content-sha256 UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD`
  - Message says "This is a duplicate header and will be overridden..." when I try to use this header
    [image]
- **Response:**
- `Status 200` but response is empty(There are MANY files in `parent-dir2`).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eureka! Found the answer in the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html)

**Winner ended up being:**

- `https://bucket.mycompany.com.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=parent-dir1/parent-dir2/`

[image]